# Flow graph aptitude solving

Tags: algorithm, graph

Got stuck in following  Flow-Graph problem.

```
Box #   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8

        3   7   2   1   5   12  4   0
```

Start

1    Put (number in box 8) into box 1.

2    Add: (number in box 1) + (number in box 2), put result into box 1.

3    Change Instruction 2: increase the second box-number mentioned in it, by 1.

4    Is the second box number mentioned in Instruction 2, greater than (number in 
  NO        box 7)?

YES

END

What number is now in box 1?

when tried,

1. b[1] = 0
2. b[1] = 0+7 = 7
3. b[1] = 7+ 2 = 9

7> 4  YES

b[1] = 9

but answer is 10. am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: Maybe you have to compute instruction 2 after making the change mentioned in instruction 3.

Comment: that's what Am doing right? @user1990169

Comment: Don't understand your step 3.

Comment: As i understoon , after change Instruction it reads as "Add the numbers from Box 1 and Box 3 , and put the result in Box 1"

Comment: What to do if the check in 4th instruction is false? Also what is number in NO box 7?